# jquery ajax call to a remote php file failing 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i've got a foo.php file which retrieves client infomation and generates an xml output with the relevant client info.

i'm trying this ajax call which does not seem to want to work

$.get('http://www.foo.php','',function(xml){
    $('samplenode',xml).each(function(i){
        //stuff done here
    }); 
}, 'xml');

i'm still new to javascript, jquery and ajax, so there might be something really silly that i'm overlooking.

(i've tried replacing foo.php with a foo.xml file with a copy/paste of a sample output, and that works fine, so it really seems to be a problem with the call to a php file.  and if i go straight to the foo.php file with my browser, the xml is all there and properly formatted, so the problem does not seem to be the php script itself.)

Comment: do you set content-type properly?

Answer (score 2):

Use 'foo.php' instead.

Answer (score 1):

is your get url correct?  You have:

```
'http://www.foo.php'
```

Should that be:

```
'http//www.mysite.com/foo.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, turns out it was a problem with the 'type' argument of the $.get function.

simply omitting it seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave the type, send you document with the correct content type by starting the php with:

```
header ("content-type: text/xml");
```